# How to right dealloc object when app goes to background?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, multitasking, dealloc

Have only one question  "How to right dealloc object when app goes to background ?". I'm working on some app, everything works great and fine. When i put app to background and then start it again it's crashes. Not immediately(app stars right where i closed it) , but when i choose some of cells or just scroll tableview for example. So i'm pretty sure that app calls already released data.

here is example of dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {


    [anObject release];
    [array release];
    [locationManager release];
    [currentLatitude release];
    [currentLongitude release];
    [filteredListContent release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any advises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I review and re-write my own code. The problem was as i expected in deallocation of memory. I used autorelease where i shouldn't. It still weird cause app did crash when i open it again.

Thanks everyone, not you guys who gift to me 2 negs, you are jerks. Don't be offended,but instead of give some advise you just give ungrounded negs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically deallocate things in your app delegate's applicationDidEnterBackground method, nothing should be deallocated for you automatically.

I have never experienced the problem you're having. Are you certain the same thing doesn't happen after a while even if you never put it in the background?

Here's a good explanation of how all of the backgrounding stuff fits together:

[Understanding iOS 4 Backgrounding and Delegate Messaging](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

Never release any object like this. Use

```
- (void)dealloc {

if(anObject){
[anObject release];
anObject = nil;
}
if(array){
[array release];
array = nil;
}
//same approach for all.

 [super dealloc];
}
```